# Clarifications on the meaning of split

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can someone tell me the meaning of the word ["split"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/split#split__2) in a part of a sentence that I read on a certain book which I don't remember anymore. Part of the sentence that I recall is:

> his death came at a time when the movement was split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it means that there was some *movement*, as in some organization with certain ideas. His death came at a time when the organization *split up* into two or more opposing factions.

[Movement](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/movement), from ODO

> A group of people working together to advance their shared political, social, or artistic ideas

[Split](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/split), from ODO

> (With reference to a group of people) divide into two or more groups